# Looking for a specific style in Biblatex

Tags: bibtex, citing, harvard-style, german

Im new to Latex in general. As Im writing a new document I wanted to try this with Latex.
Unfortunately Im not able to find the correct style for my reference and citation.

For my references:

[image: The desired reference style]

For my citations:

[Becker 2000, S.55]

Could you help me out please? :)

Comment: a MWE is needed to answer...

Answer (score 1):

Here is a start with `biblatex` and in particular my `biblatex-ext` bundle.

For most things it should be fairly clear what happens from the name of the involved commands, but if you want more details, have a look at the [`biblatex-ext` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex-contrib/biblatex-ext/biblatex-ext.pdf) and the [`biblatex` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf).

```
\documentclass[ngerman]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[
  backend=biber,
  citestyle=ext-authoryear,
  bibstyle=ext-authortitle,
  sorting=nyt,
  maxbibnames=999, maxcitenames=2,
  giveninits=true,
  uniquename=init,
  introcite=plain,
  innamebeforetitle=true,
]{biblatex}

\renewcommand*{\newunitpunct}{\addcomma\space}

\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given}
\DeclareNameAlias{ineditor}{sortname}

\DeclareFieldFormat{editortype}{\mkbibparens{#1}}
\DeclareDelimFormat{editortypedelim}{\addspace}

\DeclareFieldAlias{translatortype}{editortype}
\DeclareDelimAlias{translatortypedelim}{editortypedelim}

\DeclareDelimFormat{multinamedelim}{\addslash}
\DeclareDelimFormat[bib]{multinamedelim}{\addcomma\space}
\DeclareDelimAlias{finalnamedelim}{multinamedelim}

\DeclareDelimFormat[bib]{nametitledelim}{\addcolon\space}


\DeclareFieldFormat*{title}{\mkbibemph{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{journaltitle}{#1\isdot}
\DeclareFieldFormat{issuetitle}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat{maintitle}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat{booktitle}{#1}

\renewcommand*{\locdatedelim}{\addspace}
\renewbibmacro*{pubinstorg+location+date}[1]{%
  \printlist{#1}%
  \setunit*{\publocdelim}%
  \printlist{location}%
  \setunit*{\locdatedelim}%
  \usebibmacro{date}%
  \newunit}

\DefineBibliographyStrings{german}{
  andothers = {et\addabbrvspace al\adddot},
}

\DeclareFieldFormat{bbx@introcite}{\mkbibbrackets{#1}}
\renewcommand*{\introcitepunct}{\par}

\DeclareOuterCiteDelims{parencite}{\bibopenbracket}{\bibclosebracket}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite{sigfridsson,worman,companion,geer,westfahl:space,pines}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: [Goossens et al. 1994] Goossens, M., Mittelbach, F., Samarin, A.: The LaTeX Companion, 1. Aufl., Addison-Wesley, Reading, Mass. 1994, 528 S.]

Comment: If you are new to LaTeX you are probably new to `biblatex` as well, so please have a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/13509/35864. You will need to compile the document above with Biber (not with BibTeX). https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63852/35864 explains brilliantly what BibTeX and Biber do (in principle they do similar things, but the code above needs Biber). https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864 helps you configure your editor for Biber.