# Reference in bibliography same as in citation

Tags: biblatex, bibliographystyle

I have the following code:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[citestyle=bwl-fu, maxcitenames=3, maxbibnames=20, firstinits=true]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{literature.bib}
\renewcommand{\mkbibnamefamily}[1]{\textsc{#1}}         % Authors in small caps in citation and bibliography
\DeclareNameAlias{default}{last-first}                  % family name, given name
\renewcommand*{\multinamedelim}{\addsemicolon\space}    % semicolon between two authors
\DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumberwidth}{Test}             % print nothing in the label
\DeclareCiteCommand{\cite}                              % hyperlink authoryear to bibliography
{\usebibmacro{prenote}}
{\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
\printtext[bibhyperref]{\usebibmacro{cite}}}
{\multicitedelim}
{\usebibmacro{postnote}}
\usepackage{hyperref}


\begin{filecontents}{literature.bib}
    @article{Mueller.2018,
        author = {Müller, Michael and Gerber, Michael and Huber, Klaus},
        year = {2018},
        title = {{Irgendein Beitrag}},
        pages = {781--793},
        number = {233},
        journal = {{Mühlenzeitschrift}}
    }
    
    @book{Junker.2008,
        author = {Junker, Hans and Weber, Michael and Zehn, Olaf and Klein, Peter},
        year = {2008},
        title = {{Energieverbrauch von Mühlen}},
        publisher = {Springer},
        address = {Berlin}
    }
\end{filecontents}


\begin{document}
    
    \chapter{Test-Kapitel}
    \cite{Mueller.2018} haben eine Meinung. Aber \cite{Junker.2008} sehen das anders.
    
    \printbibliography[title=Literaturverzeichnis]
    
\end{document}
```

But instead of "Test" in the bibliography I need author (year) as a reference. I'd like to have something like:
[image: author and year as reference]

Thanks!

Comment: The question was posted and edited by two different accounts with the same screen name, this suggests you have two separate accounts and have lost control over your question. Stack Exchange staff can [merge your accounts together for you](//tex.stackexchange.com/help/user-merge). If you the accounts are not merged that will make it very difficult to communicate properly. In which case it might be wise to ask the question again and we can then close this question as a duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

`bwl-fu` is just a fairly thin wrapper around the standard `authoryear` style, so I would try to recreate what it does with [`biblatex-ext`](https://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex-ext), where you can use the option `introcite` to get the citation labels in the bibliography.

You can find out more about `introcite` and most other things used below in the [`biblatex-ext` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex-contrib/biblatex-ext/biblatex-ext.pdf).

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[
  backend=biber,
  citestyle=ext-authoryear,
  bibstyle=ext-authoryear,
  sorting=nyt,
  maxcitenames=3, maxbibnames=20,
  giveninits=true,
  introcite=plain
]{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\setlength{\bibitemsep}{\itemsep}

\DeclareInnerCiteDelimsAlias{bbx@introcite}{textcite}
\renewcommand*{\introcitepunct}{\addcolon\\}

\DeclareNameAlias{default}{family-given}
\renewcommand{\mkbibnamefamily}[1]{\textsc{#1}}

\DeclareDelimFormat{multinamedelim}{\addsemicolon\space}

\renewcommand*{\volnumdelim}{}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article,periodical]{number}{\mkbibparens{#1}}

\renewcommand*{\publocdelim}{\addcolon\space}
\renewbibmacro*{pubinstorg+location+date}[1]{%
  \printlist{#1}%
  \setunit*{\publocdelim}%
  \printlist{location}%
  \setunit*{\locdatedelim}%
  \usebibmacro{date}%
  \newunit}


\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Schon \textcite{sigfridsson} wussten \dots
Doch nicht alle wollten es wahrhaben \autocite{nussbaum,aksin,companion}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Sigfridsson und Ryde (1998): Sigfridsson, E. und U. Ryde (1998). “Comparison of methods for deriving atomic charges from the electrostatic potential and moments”. In: Journal of Computational Chemistry 19(4), S. 377–395. doi: 10.1002/(SICI)1096-987X(199803)19:4<377::AID-JCC1>3.0.CO;2-P.]

See also [Change Reference appearance with bold authoryear above entry](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/550888/35864), [Looking for a specific style in Biblatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/605998/35864)

Comment: +1 for the comment to the op's question.